# How to make view controller.m and .h files for new view controller in Xcode 6?

Tags: xcode6

I new how to do it in Xcode 5 but now it isn't as straight forward, at least for me. I used to choose Objective C Class when making a new one but in the 6 there is no C Class just a lot of different options.

Thanks in Advance,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create either a Cocoa Touch Class (iOS) or Cocoa Class (OS X) file. Make the class a subclass of UIViewController or NSViewController.